# How to exit full screen mode in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Unable to exit full screen mode in safari.

```
document.exitFullscreen()
```

doesn't work

Comment: Considering ios safari doesn't support element.requestFullsreen, how have you got into a position where you need to exitFullscreen?

Comment: I have a YouTube Iframe and I need to prevent it from full screen mode. document.exitFullscreen works perfect in other browsers but not in Safari

Comment: is this in ios? because as you should know by now, ios safari does not support this method at all

Answer (score 3):

Safari uses a `wekbit` prefix. So instead of `document.exitFullscreen()` it's just `document.webkitExitFullscreen()`.

The way I've handled this is to check for the function and use `.bind`:

```
const exitFunc = document.exitFullscreen || (document as any).webkitExitFullscreen;
const exitFullScreen = exitFunc.bind(document);

exitFullscreen();
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the following article, Safari on iOS doesn't support this method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen

Comment: I had read it before but it seems like it is impossible to use this method in Safari. Are there another methods which may be used?

Comment: in other words, safari on ios doesn't support this method - something that you could've put in the answer to make it better :p